# Ten training data in the sample model

Tags: r

My question is, for instance, I have ten different training data from the same sample, I want to get the results of these ten different data from the same regression model. Denoted by traindata[[1]],traindata[[2]],..... I used the following R code:

```
LM_10 = sapply(1:10,function(i)lm(logprice~.,data = traindata[[i]]))
```

, but I can't get the results of every data, for example,

```
pr.LM = predict(LM_10[[1]]) is not applicable.
```

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lapply(X, FUN, ...)`, that is applicable in lists

```
LM_10 = lapply(1:10,function(i)lm(logprice~.,data = traindata[[i]]))
LM_10[[1]]
pr.LM = predict(LM_10[[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'simplify' step in sapply is squashing the result into something you don't expect. Try `lapply` to get a list, then you can select its elements with `[[index]]` as in your example.